# What does feature overfitting mean?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting

How can one explain that a machine learning model has an overfit to a non machine learning person, say an analyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overfitting is a term which is referred when your model performs well on training samples than on your test samples. This means that the performance measure of your model is better on your training samples than on your test samples.

In general this occurs when you have too many predictors and less number of observations. In this case what really happens is that your model develops a decision boundary in a high dimensional space. Since you develop your model on training samples you generally (or expect to) get good result on your performance measure. But since your test samples are unseen, they may not be along the line of your decision boundary. Thus, you may get (extremely) bad result on your test samples.

Either increasing the number of training samples, or decreasing the number of predictors (but you should know which ones to remove) might result in a better model.